# Python: How to recover variable number of entries with Regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to select a variable number of entries using regular expression from a string?

For example, from a string like that:

```
line = '   @2A) lib_1, lib 2 , lib3   '
```

I would like to obtain:

```
lib = ['lib_1','lib 2','lib3']
```

For the moment, I'm using this code...but I don't know if there is a better way:

```
lib = [n.lstrip().rstrip() for n in re.findall('^\s*@\d[A-Z]\)\s*(\S+.*\S*)', line)[0].split(',')]
```

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You can use `n.strip()` instead of `n.lstrip().rstrip()`.

Comment: Instead of using regular expressions you can combine some string manipulations: `map(str.strip, line.strip().split(')')[1].split(','))`

Comment: What are the common properties of the substrings you want to find?

Answer (score 2):

If the 'lib' keyword is present in all the strings you want to process, this would do the trick.

```
re.findall('lib.?\d', line)
['lib_1', 'lib 2', 'lib3']
```

If the keyword can be anything, then

```
re.findall('\w+.?\d', line)
['lib_1', 'lib 2', 'lib3']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try searching for `lib` followed by an optional space or underscore (`[_\s]*`) followed by one or more digits (`\d+`):

```
>>> re.findall(r"lib[_\s]*\d+", line)
['lib_1', 'lib 2', 'lib3']
```

Comment: This regex is not efficient: `\w+`  will match `_` and thus `[_]` makes little sense. You'd have to restrict the `\w` class to make it more "linear".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay, let it be `lib` then :) Thanks

Comment: Well, I thought of `[^\W_]` instead of `\w`. Or even `[^\W\d_]` since the next character class is optional and then come digits. The question is a bit unclear to me (no verbose requirements are provided).